# React Animations - Slide between components

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs

I've got a new ReactJS app. I'm trying to animate between views using ReactCSSTransitionGroup plugin, but the animation classes aren't being applied as expected. No animations seem to take place. Am i missing something?

[React Animation Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { FORM_PAGE, QUOTE_PAGE } from '../Config/Pages'
import Form from './Form';
import Quote from './Quote';

class App extends Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
        transitionName="page" 
        transitionEnterTimeout={300} 
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
      >
        {this.renderPage()}
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    )
  }

  renderPage() {
    switch (this.props.currentPage) {
      case QUOTE_PAGE:
        return (<Quote />);
      case FORM_PAGE:
        return (<Form />);
      default:
        return (<Quote />)
    }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    currentPage: state.app.currentPage
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

CSS

```
 <style>
      .page-enter {
        transform: translate(100%);
      }
      .page-enter.page-enter-active {
        transform: translate(0%);
        transition: transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
      }
      .page-leave {
        transform: translate(0%);
      }
      .page-leave.page-leave-active {
        transform: translate(-100%);
        transition: transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
      }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're not setting keys on the returned components.  E.g.

```
 renderPage() {
    switch (this.props.currentPage) {
      case QUOTE_PAGE:
        return (<Quote key={'quote'} />);
      case FORM_PAGE:
        return (<Form key={'form'} />);
      default:
        return (<Quote key={'quote'} />)
    }
  }
```

Here's a fiddle showing a simplified version of your code. Click the button to see the animation.  Remove the key from Page1 and Page2 to break it.

http://jsbin.com/xoviholumi